# RediSearch library for Scala?

Tags: java, scala, redis, client-library, redisearch

I am developing Scala webservice and using Redis to store and retrive the values. I want to use RediSearch module to improve the search performance by using indexes. I have researched a lot and could not find any client library for Scala (http://redisearch.io/Clients/).

Is there any client libraries available for Scala? If not, I am planning to create a Java library package using RediSearch Java client library(https://github.com/RedisLabs/JRediSearch) & use it in my Scala project. Is it a good approach? Will it affect the performance of the web service while using Java library from Scala?

Comment: Note that asking for offsite resources is offtopic.

Comment: Just use JRediSearch from your scala code. Most people use Jedis from scala as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Scala client for RediSearch, and I don't think there's a very compelling reason why there should be one. Just as most Scala Redis users just use Jedis, you can go ahead and use JRediSearch from Scala.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for someone who comes across this later, you don't necessarily need RediSearch client to use it. You can simply use redis client of your choice from [this list](https://redis.io/clients) and simply use clients raw command to write RediSearch commands.

I had exact same issue, created a Wordpress plugin and tried using php client which is written very nice, but it don't covers all RediSearch features, so just dropped it and only used Predis (redis php client) and used its raw command.

For example: `FT.SEARCH indexName "query to search"`